# phone layout preview border not correct

Tags: android, layout

[Layout Preview android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI4aZ.png)

Does anyone know why the border is pushed to the right? XML is below, used this code for all other activities and it works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.SplashActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/TMDBLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src = "@drawable/tmdb_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this attribute in linear layout :

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Comment: Do you want set image center of screen ?

Comment: Yes, yet using any kind of gravity has no affect, as you can see from the image there is a white space not covered to the left of the screen. This should be filled, as it is other activities I have used with the same code. I hope that makes sense.